# ArgumentCaptor usage in Unit Tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, junit5

I am trying to create a Unit Test for the following service method:

```
public CompanyDTO update(CompanyRequest companyRequest, UUID uuid) {

    final Company company = companyRepository.findByUuid(uuid)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("Not found"));            
    
    company.setName(companyRequest.getName());

    final Company saved = companyRepository.save(company);
    return new CompanyDTO(saved);
}
```

I created the following Unit Test:

```
@InjectMocks
private CompanyServiceImpl companyService;

@Mock
private CompanyRepository companyRepository;

@Captor
ArgumentCaptor<Company> captor;



@Test
public void testUpdate() {
    final Company company = new Company();
    company.setName("Company Name");

    final UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    final CompanyRequest request = new CompanyRequest();
    request.setName("Updated Company Name");
  
    when(companyRepository.findByUuid(uuid))
        .thenReturn(Optional.ofNullable(company));        
    when(companyRepository.save(company)).thenReturn(company);

    CompanyDTO result = companyService.update(request, uuid);

    /* here we get the "company" parameter value that we send to save method 
    in the service. However, the name value of this paremeter is already 
    changed before passing to save method. So, how can I check if the old 
    and updated name value? */
    Mockito.verify(companyRepository).save(captor.capture());

    Company savedCompany = captor.getValue();

    assertEquals(request.getName(), savedCompany.getName());
}
```

As far as I know, we use `ArgumentCaptor` to catch the value we pass to a method. In this example, I need to catch the value at correct time and compare the updated value of name sent to the update method and the returned value of name property after update. However, I cannot find how to test it properly and add necessary comment to my test method. So, how should I use `ArgumentCaptor` to verify my update method updates the company with the given value ("Updated Company Name").

Comment: You don't need an argument captor at all,you can just mock the company, then `verify(company).setName(updatedName)`.

Comment: Thanks for reply, what do you mean? Could you post the Test method by modifying necessary parts.

Comment: @daniu And also could you please give an example scenario for we need to use `ArgumentCaptor`?

Comment: @daniu Chico? Are you there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your scenario for an `ArgumentCaptor`.

Code under test:

```
public void createProduct(String id) {
  Product product = new Product(id);
  repository.save(product);
}
```

Note that a) we create an object within the tested code, b) we want to verify something specific with that object, and c) we don't have access to that object after the call. Those are pretty much the exact circumstances where you need a captor.

You can test it like this:

```
void testCreate() {
  final String id = "id";
  ArgumentCaptor<Product> captor = ArgumentCaptor.for(Product.class);

  sut.createProduct(id);

  // verify a product was saved and capture it
  verify(repository).save(captor.capture());
  final Product created = captor.getValue();

  // verify that the saved product which was captured was created correctly
  assertThat(created.getId(), is(id));
}
```

Comment: **1.** Thanks for good explanations. **verify a product was saved and capture it:** --> do you mean to capture the `product` value we pass to `repository.save()` method?

Comment: **2.** In your example, we used captor to get the `product` variable created by `Product product = new Product(id);`. However, in my example, do I need to catch the `company` variable that is passed to `companyRepository.save(company)` ? It seems to be a little bit meaningless as I can get almost all values in my update method. But I am confused, what do you think?

Comment: @Henry 1. yes, what is captured is the parameter passed to the save() method. 2. You don't need to capture any value in your case because nothing is created inside the test method that you can't access outside. Have you read my other answer?

Comment: Yes I read and add comment. I understand the need for ArgumentCaptor usage. But your other answer may be updated according to my comment for it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would write this test case, with explanations as code comments.

```
@Test
public void testUpdate() {
    // we make this a mock so we can analyze it later
    final Company company = mock(Company.class);

    // no need to have the same String literal twice
    final String updatedName = "Updated Company Name";

    // we make this a mock because only that one method is used
    // if you create an actual object, you'll need to adjust this test 
    // when the constructor changes later
    final CompanyRequest request = mock(CompanyRequest.class);
    when(request.getName()).thenReturn(updatedName);
  
    // we don't really care about the actual uuid, so any() will do here
    when(companyRepository.findByUuid(any()))
        .thenReturn(Optional.ofNullable(company));
    when(companyRepository.save(any())).thenReturn(company);

    // setup complete, let's go
    CompanyDTO result = companyService.update(request, UUID.randomUUID());

    // we want to make sure the name change has been applied
    Mockito.verify(company.setName(udpatedName);
    // make sure it has been saved as well
    Mockito.verify(companyRepository).save(company);

    // verify that the returned dto actually contains the company we've been working on
    Company savedCompany = result.getCompany();
    assertSame(savedCompany, company);
}
```

Note that this does not answer your actual question about how to use an argument captor, but that's because that was an X-Y problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot good explanations. However, when I tried this approach, I see that `when(companyRepository.save(company)).thenReturn(company);` causing always the test is passed. I think this approach needs a little bit changes. Any idea?

Comment: @Henry how do you mean, "always pass"? The methods works correctly, why would the test fail?

Comment: In ` when(companyRepository.save(company)).thenReturn(company);` statement, we pass `company` to the `save` method and it returns the same `company` values. So, in this case it `company` parameter values do not make any sense.